# How to evaluate probability distribution given the parameter is greater than a certain value?

Tags: probability, statistics, hypothesis-testing, p-value

Let X ~ Binomial(n, p)

$H_{0}$: p >= .5

$H_{1}$: p < .5

How do we evaluate the p-value?

ie. $P(X \ge x \mid p >= .5)$

I have seen settings where this is just interpreted as $P(X \ge x \mid p=.5)$, but I'm not sure how this is the same thing.

Comment: This makes no sense. P-value is computed assuming that the null hypothesis is true in the sense that $p = .5.$

Answer (score 0):

your system of Hypothesis is equivalent to the following

$$ 
\begin{cases}
\mathcal{H}_0: p=\frac{1}{2}, \\
\mathcal{H}_1: p<\frac{1}{2}, 
\end{cases}$$

Thus the p-value is calculated as follows:

$$\mathbb{P}\Bigg[X\leq k|p=\frac{1}{2}\Bigg]$$

---

Example: to test the Hypothesis System above stated, we use a random sample of size $n=15$ observing $k=4$ successes.

The p-value is $5.92\%$ as well represented in the following drawing

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer. In the drawing, I'm assuming this is for a fixed p=.5, right? I'm wondering what the statistical justification is for why we can treat the two hypotheses equivalently.